Ime callback not found. Ignoring unregisterReceivedCallback
I am a noob in mobile app development.
Scenario
Within Dialog, within Column, I have a text field and a Button.
(Button belongs to material3. For the text field, I have tried various ones available under android.widget as well as androidx.compose.material3)
The Composable function containing the Dialog is invoked from another Composable using navController.navigate. The button, on click, makes an API call via ViewModel via Repository and then invokes navController.popBackStack().
Problem
When the IME keyboard is open for the text field, if I click on the button, then I get the error.
Ime callback not found. Ignoring unregisterReceivedCallback. callbackId: 77948589
When the keyboard is not open, if I click on the button, then there's no error.
What I have tried
Have tried multiple things, including focusManager.clearFocus() at the beginning of the button click, specifying imeAction = ImeAction.None as part of text field's keyboardOptions.
The problem is similar to that mentioned in Android Ime callback not found issue on AlertDialog dismiss, but that doesn't contain any solution.
Details about the App.

Compose only
Android SDK 14.0 API Level 34 Revision 3
Build tool Gradle 8.6
Kotlin Compiler 1.9.0 Language version 2.0 API version 2.0 JVM Target 1.8
Dependencies I included: ViewModel 2.8.0, Navigation
2.7.7, Retrofit 2.11.0, Moshi 1.14.0 (Everything else default - Empty Activity project created just 3 days ago)

